# Android: GridView: how to load only the items that are displayed on screen when scroll?

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, scrollview

I have a gridView with a lot of images (bitmaps).

How I can load only the ones are displayed on screen and load the others only when they will be displayed scrolling my gridview?

Many thanks

PS: Please show me an example.

Comment: Did you solve your problem i am facing the same problem if you can help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this docs from Google](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html), a part is dedicated to gridviews.